# iPhone - How to play a sound on button touch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uibutton

I'm trying to make a button play a sound upon touching the button. I can get the sound to play with the Touch Up Inside option but that's not what I'm looking for because the sound only plays after the button is released.

I've tried to use touchesBegan to play the sound upon touching the button but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas why?

Thanks

My code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    if([touch view] == doneButton) {


NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"click" ofType:@"caf"];
AVAudioPlayer* clickAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

clickAudio.delegate=self;
[clickAudio play];

    }
```

}

Comment: are you yring to do like a piano app? and when the user holds it down, the sound continues to play

Comment: you know, you could use a UIButton, and do something else other than touch up inside, perhaps, like 'Touch Down'

Comment: Touch Down works but I don't want the button to trigger my modalview until the button is lifted.  No, I'm not doing a piano app, lol... Too many of those out there. This is just for my preference.

Comment: So why not play the sound on touch down and trigger the modal view on touch up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `UIButton`. Call `-play` on touch down and call `-stop` on touch up.